# Is it possible to review an iPhone app from browser?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

I visited apps.apple.com while logged in and I see the ratings but I can't review. Is this possible to review an iPhone app from browser? It's very annoying (at the limit of mental breakdown) to write a proper review form a mobile device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not something Apple puts up a web interface to allow reviews off device.

However, you can connect any USB keyboard to your iOS device using a USB adapter and most bluetooth keyboards work very well if you have one handy to try pairing.

I too find myself longing for a proper keyboard when writing due to years of habit forming. Bringing your preferred tool to iOS makes it much easier to compose even with the small screen in my experience.

Worst case, pen your review in iCloud version of notes / pages / wherever and save the text to the device so it can sync over or just be there on the storage and copy/paste if you can't find a better workaround.

Comment: Plugging a keyboard to the mobile device. Now that's something I've never thought nor tried. Will give it a try later and mark this one as answer if I find it convenient enough to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I know of people that have written entire books on their phone. Bringing my magic keyboard with my phone on one trip was revelatory in how much work I thought I couldn't do, but discovered I could with that one affordance.

Comment: Unfortunately I need hardware that I don't have in order to test the keyboard part. I found it even easier to use a cloud storage system to transfer any text (not just reviews) from PC to iPhone. Though this answer answers the basic question so I've accepted it.